# orderBy dd/mm/yyyy by year angular

Tags: angularjs, date

The data I am receiving from a webservice is formatted as dd/mm/yyyy. The problem with this is when sorting, it sorts by dd rather than yyyy.

```
<td ng-repeat="thead in resultHeader">
    <a href="" ng-click="order(thead.line)">{{thead.head}}</a>
    <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === thead.line" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
</td>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.order = function(predicate) {
    var results = $scope.model.resultList;
    $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
    $scope.predicate = predicate;
    $scope.model.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.model.beginFrom = 0;
};
```

How can I sort this data by yyyy with my current set up?

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "ShipmentDate": "06\/08\/2012"
}
```

Comment: Parse the string to a Date, and store the date in the object. The sort by date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you converted your date strings to `Date` objects, you can use the `orderBy:` filter to sort by date.

```
<td ng-repeat="thead in resultHeader | orderBy:'ShipmentDate':shouldBeReversedOrder ">
    <a href="" ng-click="shouldBeReversedOrder = !shouldBeReversedOrder">{{thead.head}}</a>
    <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === thead.line" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
</td>
```

When you want to display the date back in a proper formate you can use `{{thead.ShipmentDate | 'yyyy-mm-dd'}}` to format it for you.

Comment: Perfect. I just added new date properties to each object and sorted by that. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

The key part is to add a `$filter` to your module and use that $filter to get the `Date` value from the string. you can use `Date.parse('dd/mm/yyyy')` to get the time in float, and then run an Array.sort() to your data.

Answer (score 2):

Use the custom order for this. Look:

```js
function MyCtrl($scope, orderByFilter) {
    $scope.sortedFriends = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        age: 25,
        dateTest: '10/10/2015'
    }, {
        name: 'Jimmy',
        age: 25,
        dateTest: '10/12/2015'
    },{
        name: 'Mary',
        age: 28,
        dateTest: '10/09/2009'
    }, {
        name: 'Ed',
        age: 27,
        dateTest: '30/03/2014'
    },{
        name: 'Andrew',
        age: 27,
        dateTest: '11/11/2016'
    }];
    
    $scope.orderByCustom = function(friend) {
        console.log(friend)
       return friend.dateTest.split('/')[2];
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="friend in sortedFriends | orderBy:orderByCustom"">
           {{friend}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```